# Python: Pandas Grouper( ) function timestamp selection

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the sample data:

```
|  group |   unix_time |   
|    1   |  1565938335 |   # 6:52:15 AM
|    1   |  1565938350 |   # 6:52:30 AM
|    1   |  1565938390 |   # 6:53:10 AM
```

Here is the code.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['unix_time'], unit='s')  #convert unix time to datetime
for g, t in df.groupby(['group', pd.Grouper(freq='60s', key='datetime')]):
    print(g, t)
```

The above code will divide the data into 2 groups:

- group 1: row 1 and 2
- group 2: row 3

The reason is that, in **Grouper()** function, the freq = '60s' will count from the start of minute (6:52:00, 6:53:00), instead of 6:52:15. Grouper( ) uses default timestamp:

```
timestamp 6:52:00
timpstamp 6:53:00
```

However, I want to put them into the same group, **as long as the time difference is within 60 seconds** (6:52:15 AM and 6:53:10 AM are within 60 secs)

I read Grouper man-page, but seems no such option. How to revise the code?

Comment: how is determined start time for rest of data?

Comment: @zaraki: for example, assume there's a row 4 time (still belongs to group 1) later than 6:53:15AM, then it becomes the new start time. in other words, row 1-3 is group 1.1, row 4 is group 1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My option is to use time index with pandas [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1,1,1,1], "time": [1565938335, 1565938350, 1565938394, 1565938395]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
df.index = df['datetime']
print(df)

for item in df['datetime'].resample('60s', kind='period'):
    print(item)
```

Input data:

```
                     group        time            datetime
datetime                                                  
2019-08-16 06:52:15      1  1565938335 2019-08-16 06:52:15
2019-08-16 06:52:30      1  1565938350 2019-08-16 06:52:30
2019-08-16 06:53:14      1  1565938394 2019-08-16 06:53:14
2019-08-16 06:53:15      1  1565938395 2019-08-16 06:53:15
```

Output:

```
(Period('2019-08-16 06:52:15', '60S'), datetime
2019-08-16 06:52:15   2019-08-16 06:52:15
2019-08-16 06:52:30   2019-08-16 06:52:30
2019-08-16 06:53:14   2019-08-16 06:53:14
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns])

(Period('2019-08-16 06:53:15', '60S'), datetime
2019-08-16 06:53:15   2019-08-16 06:53:15
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns])
```